# Asp.net populate tree view linq to entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, treeview

Here is a better explanation of what I need it, I think is done most of the part but I just cant figure it out on ViewMode. Please if someone can help me, thanks!

I have a List of KeyWords (overview) and I want to Edit/Insert and View the information related to an specific KeyWord or insert a new one.
On this details keyword page for insert, edit and view, I have to show a treeview, with categories and themes, parent node are categories and 
childs themes. The user can check any of these themes (treeview based on checkboxes) to relate the selected keyword with those themes.
For example for the category Science I have themes Mathematics, Physics, Geography, if I want the keyword Geometry, I could check on the treeview
Mathematics. On view mode, I just need to show the selected themes and category parent, but for the insert and edit has to show all and also the themes are checked.

I have this entities and navigation properties and an data example:

Entity Option(OptionId, ParentId, Description, virtual navigation property KeyWordOptions)
KeyWordOption(OptionId, KeywordID, virtual navigation property Option)

```
 Option Entity  
        OptionId    ParentID  Description
        1           0         Informatics
        2           1         Development
        3           0         Architecture
        4           1         Systems
        5           1         Hardware
        6           3         Civil Engineering
        7           1         Software


  KeyWordOption Entity
       OptionId   KeywordID    ID KeywordDescription
        1         8            8   Visual Studio
        2         8            2   Autocad
        4         2            5   Monitor
        5         5            9   Eclipse
        2         9
        7             8
        7             2
        7             9



Result Would be for Eclipse keyword(id = 9) at EditMode:

Informatics
    Development (checked)
    System      
    Hardware
    Software (checked)
Architecture
    Civil Engineering
```

Result Would be for Eclipse keyword(id = 9) at ViewMode:

```
Informatics
    Development (checked)
    Software (checked)
```

My code is:

BindTreeView(OptionList, null);

```
 private void BindTreeView(IEnumerable<Opcion> OptionList, TreeNode parentNode)
        {
            var nodes = OptionList.Where(x => parentNode == null ? x.ParentID == 0 : x.ParentID == int.Parse(parentNode.Value));

            if (mode != FormViewMode.View)
            {
                foreach (var node in nodes)
                {
                    TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode();
                    newNode.Text = node.Description.ToString();
                    newNode.Value = node.OptionID.ToString();

                    if (parentNode == null)
                    {
                        TreeViewOptions.Nodes.Add(newNode);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (node.KeyWordOptions.Where(c => c.KeywordID == _idKeyWord).Count() > 0)
                        {
                            newNode.Checked = true;
                            parentNode.Expand();
                        }
                        parentNode.ChildNodes.Add(newNode);
                    }
                    BindTreeView(OptionList, newNode);               
                }

            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var node in nodes)
                {
                    TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode();
                    newNode.Text = node.Descripcion.ToString();
                    newNode.Value = node.OpcionID.ToString();

                    if (parentNode == null && node.KeyWordOptions.Where(c => c.KeywordID == _idKeyWord).Count() > 0)
                    {
                        TreeViewOptions.Nodes.Add(newNode);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (node.KeyWordOptions.Where(c => c.KeywordID == _idKeyWord).Count() > 0)
                        {
                            newNode.Checked = true;
                            parentNode.Expand();
                        }

                        parentNode.ChildNodes.Add(newNode);

                    }
                    BindTreeView(OptionList, newNode);
                }

            }


        }
    }
```

I dont know what I have to do to exclude the `Nodes` that don't match the `KeywordId`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you edit your question to include more information on what specifically you are having problems with, what you have tried and exactly why it didn't work - this will help us better understand you question.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Maybe this in one of your loop, then (you should refactor, by the way) ?

```
foreach (var node in nodes.Where
            (x => x.KeyWordOptions.Any(k => k.KeywordId == _idKeyWord));
```

Comment: But in that case on edit and inser I cant show the Categories and themes that are not related with the KeywordId, but if the user wants can add new themes for the keyword.

Comment: @user2528557 oh, and editing /inserting are related to `FormViewMode.View` ? See edit maybe...

Comment: For editing and Inserting I show the same, all the tree with the cheked themes, and for the view mode, just the ones are checked. BUt I am a bit confuse with the recursivity.

Comment: ohhh ok i know what u mean...why do i need refactor? thanks!!

Comment: @user2528557 well, when you write 2 times exactly the same code (with just one different parameter), it's usually time to extract it to another method...

Comment: Did you see the post updated, I explain a little better what is happening...or what I have to do, for the inserting and edit is ok, the problems comes with the view. About refactoring that was what i modified because before was in two methods, but you are also right i have to refactor more this method and take the iqual part to another method and call it when need it, but with the recursivity make me thing harder.